# Can "before" modify a noun like an adjective?

Tags: conjunctions

I would like to know whether "before" can modify a noun like an adjective, for example as follows:

> This picture shows the pizza I bought before being baked.

[image]

Comment: I see *no* problem!

Comment: It sounds weird. Your sentence is somewhat infelicitous since the relative clause reads "(that) I bought the pizza before being baked" (it implies "before I was being baked"!). It would be much better to say "This picture shows the pizza I bought before it was baked". In any case "before" is not a constituent", but is head of the PP "before being baked".

Comment: As BillJ says, it's especially awkward/funny because *baked* is also a slang word for "high on marijuana", so "...I bought before being baked" can be read as "...before I got high on marijuana."

Comment: Neither "I bought" nor "baked" is important. My question is whether "This picture shows the pizza before being cooked." is correct.

Comment: @rama9 - Yes, that's fine, although *before* is really modifying an entire phrase, not just a noun.  We use *before* with gerunds and participles all the time.  For example, ["If the employee died before receiving payment..."](https://books.google.com/books?id=N_cn_3MJEWoC&pg=PA146&dq=%22before+receiving%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwic5Orv9_3aAhWrd98KHfUUAQ0Q6AEINzAD)